# Are the comparison operators for sets in Python 3.3 broken?

Tags: python

Here's the code that I used:

```
>>> a = set([1,2,2])
>>> b = set([1,1,2])
>>> a
    {1, 2, 2}
>>> b
    {1, 1, 2}
>>> a <= b
    True 
>>> a.__le__(b)
    True
```

Clearly `a` is not a subset of `b`. Also, looking at the documentation code from collections.py, I'm a bit worried since this is something crucial, as in the docstring for the class `Set` we have them say

```
"""...
To override the comparisons (presumably for speed, as the
semantics are fixed), all you have to do is redefine __le__ and
then the other operations will automatically follow suit."""
```

All other methods use `__le__`. So am I alone on this one?

Comment: Are you saying that your Python 3.3 genuinely returned `{1, 2, 2}` after you typed `a`, as shown in your transcript?  If so, something is very wrong.

Comment: @DSM -- I was just reading the transcript again too and then I started to understand the downvotes.

Answer (score 7):

In fact `a` is a subset of `b`. That's because duplicate values are not allowed in a set.

The [documentation](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset) makes this clear:

> A set object is an unordered collection of distinct hashable objects.

The key word in that sentence is *distinct*.

So, it follows that, and can easily be verified, that your three sets are all equal to each other.

```
{1, 2, 2} == {1, 2}
{1, 1, 2} == {1, 2}
```

Comment: Alright, I was thinking along the lines of multisets, where duplicates are counted. Thanks for the info. Now at least I know the limitations of the documentation.

Comment: @noobProgrammer What limitations are you referring to?

Comment: @phant0m That the class `Set` doesn't include the mutliset data structure, in which {1,2,2} != {1,2}. Essentially I can't use the `Set` class and expect the correct outcome for multisets.

Comment: @noobProgrammer -- You might want to consider a `collections.Counter` for something like that.  then you would have a data structure `{1:1,2:2}` or `{1:2,2:1}` -- e.g. a number and how many times it is present.

Comment: @noobProgrammer You can't expect one datastructure to do multiple things. Would you like it to be called `SetButNotAMultiSet`? As shown in the quote, the documentation it's quite clear about it being a set and not a multiset. So `Set` acts like a set, I don't see the problem.

Comment: @noobProgrammer -- I've added a recipe for how you can use a Counter to get whether one Counter is a subset of another one.

Answer (score 6):

No.  The comparison operators for `set` are definitely not broken.  `a` certainly is a subset of `b`.  Don't forget that when your sets are built, the duplicate values will be removed!

If you try printing `a` and `b`, you'll find that they both are the set: `{1, 2}`.  In fact, they are equivalent sets and therefore each is a subset of the other.

---

If you're looking for a multiset, perhaps you would like to look into a [`collections.Counter`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) for your data structure.  The documentation even states:

> The Counter class is similar to bags or multisets in other languages.

Since Counters support `intersection`, you could easily test if one counter is the subset of another:

```
def counter_issubset(a,b):
    return a == (a & b)
```